# Oracle JD Edwards EquipementManager Documentation

Tags: jdeveloper, jde, jdedwards

Where can I find the full API documentation of `EquipmentManager`? the official/unofficial docs and books keep pointing to the javadoc packages `(JP170001,J1700001,J1700002)` which I couldn't find.

P.S I'm looking for an online documentation (without downloading the whole software to get its documentation).

Comment: Its not available on support.oracle.com ? I guess all Oracle product have documentation available there

Comment: yes there is some kind of documents there but they lack anything useful on how to use the EquipmentManager, the documents references javadoc packages for more details which I couldn't find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this answer is 3 months old, but you can find a good deal of information on Equipment Management in this Oracle Doc:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16582_01/doc.91/e15144/managing_equipment.htm#EOASM00153

This doc will mention that P1702 is the Fast Path app ID to get to the application.  From the application within JDE, you can run the Data Browser to view some of the underlying table information:

V1201R [F1201/1217 Equipment Master]

This app will use the view 1201R that utilizes tables F1201 and F1217.

It doesn't sound like you have the application installed, but this website will have plenty of table information for these two tables:

http://jderef.com/?schema=910&system=&table=F1217

If you find yourself struggling with the underlying tables, JDERef.com should be a good starting point.

I also found this online reference that directly mentions those Javadoc's in regards to this API.  It's from version 9.0 but seems to have a good deal of information, including the tables mentioned above, and the packages you mentioned:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15156_01/e1apps90pbr0/eng/psbooks/1afi/chapter.htm?File=1afi/htm/1afi09.htm

However, it seems to point mostly to where to find the Javadoc through the Enterprise One install directory (example): C:\B9\STAGINGA\java\javadoc

If you still need this exact javadoc, I can get it for you this evening.  I'll just install JDE and pull it from the install directory.

**UPDATE:  As promised, here's the Javadocs you requested.**
[Link to Javadocs](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1O0yw_11NnBlhsxZ3t5Ajb8CUMbPnBAdX)

**UPDATE #2:**  This also just dawned on me, but you can go to Oracle's [eDelivery website](https://edelivery.oracle.com), and search for the JD Edwards Standalone software.  You can scroll through the list until you see the "REL:JD Edwards EnterpriseOne Standalone 9.2.0.0".  Download the 4 files and unpack them.  One of the files will have a single folder inside that says DEMO.  The javadocs are located in DEMO\Java\Javadocs folder.  On a standard release in the real world, the DEMO folder would be the folder with the proper instance name.  Good luck to you!

Comment: Thank you very much, it would be great if you could upload the javadocs... thanks in advance

Comment: My apologies for not getting back to you.  I had a REALLY hard time getting JDE installed, but I was able to successfully install the standalone client on a development machine.  I'll see if I can export this tonight.  Then I'll edit my post with the location.